# Replacement Parts for In-Ground Grill

Tags: gas, valve

I need a new grill, and I'm going to try to get this in-ground grill up and running.  This is a natural gas line that's run from the house.  It's been unused in the seven years that we've been in the house.  Does anyone know which parts I can use to replace this broken down valve so I can connect to a new grill(not yet purchased)?

I would like for it to continue to have a shutoff, and also be secure to the base which is still very sturdy despite the surface rust.  The current "valve", i.e. second parts from the top has a nut holding it to the base.

Do you think the second part can be reused and just replace the top part?  That would make my search for the needed parts easier but obviously need it to be safe.

[image]

Comment: Although shopping is off topic it could be reworded to suggest the type of parts needed, we would also need to know if this is natural gas, or LP / propane.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not reusing anything ; disconnect it at the copper tubing and put in a new stainless flex pipe ( and adapter as necessary) to connect to a new grill. When I replaced a similar grill , I also found the steel pedestal tube/pipe was  also severely weakened by corrosion at ground level.

Comment: Thanks, do you meant just that top piece?  Or the top two pieces?  If you mean the top two pieces, then that's what I've been looking for but have been having trouble finding an equivalent.

Comment: The center component looks like an LPG regulator ; the new grill source should have those if one does not come with the a grill.